# How to make continuous map of Eurasia?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, coordinates, clip, asia

I have a raster map of Eurasia, as shown here:

[image]

I want to move the Kamchatka Peninsula (on the far left side of the map) to the right side, so that the map is continuous and I can crop it to Eurasia alone/I don't want to have to include a giant blank space where the Atlantic Ocean and the Americas go.

How can I make this happen? I am using R with the raster and rgdal packages, but I am also comfortable with other GIS softwares (i.e. GDAL, GRASS GIS).

Comment: move your meridian from 0 (Greenwich) https://seethedatablog.wordpress.com/2016/12/31/r-shift-centralprime-meridian-of-world-map/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use QGIS, you can easily define a custom projection, based on an existing projection. Let's say you want to use `EPSG:4326` (WGS 84) with prime meridian shifted from Greenwich to 90° East. This solution works the same way for modifying other projections as well.

Open `Menu Settings / Custom Projections…` and click `Copy parameters from existing CRS` - the small copy-icon on the right, see red box in the screenshot:

*Custom projection dialog: here, the values were already modified to `PRIMEM["Greenwich",90,`. In the textbox name, define a name for the custom CRS so that you can easily recognize it:*
[image]

Select the existing CRS you want to modify, here `EPSG:4326`. In the line saying `PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,` (highlighted in red), replace `0` by `90`:

```
PRIMEM["Greenwich",90,
```

Then go to the last line and delete `ID["EPSG",4326]` (the last, final closing square bracket `]` should remain).

*Screenshot: this is how the original `EPSG:4326` WKT-definition looks like. Highlighted in red where you have to make your changes:*
[image]

And that's how the result looks like:

[image]